# Magento: Dynamically generated css class changes when changing language from English to Arabic

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I have used some class name in category page that are dynamically generated and used that class name to write css in style.css page.
Now the problem is when I change the store from English to Arabic, all the dynamically generated class name changes to Arabic.
How to keep these class name in English even if I change the store.

Comment: can you show your phtml file

Comment: <?php
$filternm = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", str_replace(":","",$this->getName())));
?>
<ul class="no-style <?php echo $filternm."-main";?>">
    <!--CODE GOES HERE-->
</ul>

Comment: $this->getName() is actually product attribute name which is coming in arabic for arabic store..

Answer (score 1):

When you change from one language to another language magento translate all the text which written like blow:

```
 <?php echo $this->__('yourclass') ?>
```

So if you define your class name like above than just replace with below code:

```
<?php echo 'yourclass'; ?>
```

I hope it will help you.

If you want to show your attribute name same for all the site than you can set it from admin->Attributes->Manage Attributes->Select your attribute->Manage Label / Options tab.
After that in manage title section just add the title store wise.
Note: If you want keep label than only add the lalbel in admin's textbox so it will be used for other site.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but here 'yourclass' is name of product's attribute which is coming dynamically in English for English store and Arabic for Arabic store. I need it in English for all store.

Comment: @BikashKaushik Please check i have updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not what I want. Actually I want to access English store's attribute value in Arabic store.